# Avoiding repeating code with Linq query + optional params

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring, dry

Given the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a games high scores
/// </summary>
public static List<Score> GetGameHighScores(int gameID, HighScoreType type, int? skip = null, int? take  = null)
{
    var r = new List<Score>();

    using (var db = new ArcadeContext())
    {
        var q = new List<ArcadeScore>();

        if (skip != null && take != null)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case HighScoreType.ScoreRank:
                    q =
                        db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.ScoreRank > 0)
                            .OrderBy(c => c.ScoreRank)
                            .Skip(skip.Value)
                            .Take(take.Value)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
                case HighScoreType.UserRank:
                    q =
                        db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.UserRank > 0)
                            .OrderBy(c => c.UserRank)
                            .Skip(skip.Value)
                            .Take(take.Value)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case HighScoreType.ScoreRank:
                    q =
                        db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.ScoreRank > 0)
                            .OrderBy(c => c.ScoreRank)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
                case HighScoreType.UserRank:
                    q =
                        db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.UserRank > 0)
                            .OrderBy(c => c.UserRank)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
            }
        }
        r.AddRange(q.Select(arcadeScore => new Score(arcadeScore)));
    }
    return r;
}
```

Where `skip` and `take` are optional paramters (used for when pagination is required), what's the best way to fetch the correct records without repeating myself like above?

Comment: use a ternary operator to replace the switch

Comment: In my opinion the repeated code is in the LINQ query, not the take.  The only thing that really differs is the `orderBy`  You could reduce this to a single query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of switching between four separate queries, build single query according to your conditions:

```
IQueryable<Score> query = db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID);

switch(type)
{
    case HighScoreType.ScoreRank:
        query = query.Where(c => c.ScoreRank > 0).OrderBy(c => c.ScoreRank);
        break;
    case HighScoreType.UserRank:
        query = query.Where(c => c.UserRank > 0).OrderBy(c => c.UserRank);
        break;
}

if (skip.HasValue && take.HasValue)
   query = query.Skip(skip.Value).Take(take.Value);

return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `IEnumerable` is not executed until you call `ToList` you can simply move those outside the switch statement and then call `ToList`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the coalesce operator to provide default values:

```
.Skip(skip ?? 0)
.Take(take ?? int.MaxValue)
```

Comment: Would this not still result in there being two blocks of (essentially identical) code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, extract this to a method so that you would only call OrderBy and Skip when they want the paginated one.

```
db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.ScoreRank > 0)
                                .OrderBy(c => c.ScoreRank).

db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.UserRank > 0)
                            .OrderBy(c => c.UserRank)
```

Into

```
private IEnumerable<ArcadeScore> GetArcadeOverallScore(int gameId)
{
   return db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.ScoreRank > 0)
                                    .OrderBy(c => c.ScoreRank)
}

private IEnumerable<ArcadeScore> GetArcadeUserScore(int gameId)
{
   return db.ArcadeScores.Where(c => c.GameID == gameID && c.UserRank > 0)
                                .OrderBy(c => c.UserRank)
}
```